# On the leading coefficient of a polynomial which takes integer values at every integer argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with  complex coefficients of degree $k$ with leading coefficient $a_k$ such that $f(n) \in \mathbb Z, \forall n \in \mathbb Z$, then is it true that $|a_k| \ge \dfrac 1{k!}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials ${T \choose n} := \frac{T(T-1)\times\ldots\times(T-n+1)}{n!}$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ constitute a basis of $\mathbf{C}[T]$, by an obvious degree argument. Now, if $P\in \mathbf{C}[T]$ is such that $P(\mathbf{Z})\subseteq \mathbf{Z}$, writing $P = \sum_{n=0}^k b_k {T \choose k}$ in this basis with the $a_k$'s in $\mathbf{C}$, and evaluating $P$ at integers, we see that the first coefficient $b_0$ of $P$ in this basis must be an integer, and also the sum $b_0+b_1$ of the two first coefficients in this basis must be an integer, so that $b_1$ is an integer, *etc*. Finally, you see that all coefficients $b_k$ of $P$ in this basis are integers. We shown that the set of $P\in \mathbf{C}[T]$ such that $P(\mathbf{Z})\subseteq \mathbf{Z}$ (the set of so-called *integer-valued polynomials*) is equal to the $\mathbf{Z}$-module generated by the $T \choose n$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$.

Now, what is the leading coefficient of $T \choose n$ ? it is $\frac{1}{n!}$. What is the leading coefficient of $P$ ? It is $b_k \frac{1}{k!}$. This is obviously in absolute value $\geq$ $\frac{1}{k!}$ as $b_k\not=0$ is an integer, so that $|b_k|\geq 1$. As $b_k \frac{1}{k!}$ is also the leading coefficient $a_k$ of $P$ (that it, its leading coefficient in the usual basis of polynomials) I guess that this answers your question.

*Remark.* We seen in passing that a polynomial with complex coefficients that takes integer values on integers is in fact a polynomial with rational coefficients.